# How to edit UITextFiled in Iphone..?

Tags: ios4

How to edit UITextFiled in Iphone,once i have type something but we can't edit it from textfield.
please help me.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([tfieldDOB.text length] == 4)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
    }
    else if([tfieldDOB.text length]==7)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use UITextFieldDelegate.

```
@interface KInitUserViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

implement delegates...

```
// Delegate UITextField
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    //here you can submit your changes....    
    return YES;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work for you.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (textField == tfieldDOB) {

        if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {// This codition for while taping back space on the keyboard
            return YES;
        }
        NSString *currentText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if (currentText.length == 4 || currentText.length == 7) {
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",currentText];
            return NO;
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```